# Is there heat associated with the loss of kinetic energy in an object in a gravitational field?

Tags: thermodynamics, gravity, mass, potential-energy

Assume you throw a ball into the air from the surface of the Earth.

When the ball reaches its maximum height, it will have a velocity of zero, albeit for a brief moment. Before this moment, its kinetic energy is greater than zero. Moreover, at all times prior to this moment, its kinetic energy is decreasing, due to the effect of gravity, pulling it back down.

Is there heat associated with the kinetic energy lost by the ball?

If not, how is energy conserved?

If not, how is momentum conserved?

I'm asking this question knowing that the typical answer will rely upon potential energy, but that doesn't get to the point, which is that the ball has real kinetic energy that can be converted into heat prior to reaching its maximum height -

Where does this energy go?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there heat associated with the kinetic energy lost by the ball?

Heat is a process, not a thing.  There's no heat transfer here, and there's no change in the ball's thermal energy.

> If not, how is energy conserved?

We say that the mechanical energy of the system ($KE + PE$) is constant.  Loss of kinetic energy is equal to the gain of potential energy.

> If not, how is momentum conserved?

Why should it not be conserved here?  What is your system?  If the system is "the ball", then momentum is not conserved.  But since the system is acted upon by an outside force, this is not surprising.  If the system is the "the ball plus the earth", then momentum is conserved because the gravitational pull from the ball is changing the speed of the earth.  The changes in momentum cancel out.

> the ball has real kinetic energy that can be converted into heat prior to reaching its maximum height -

It could be converted into many forms of energy.  We could have it hit a plate that pulls a rope and spins a generator, so it turns into electrical energy.

> Where does this energy go?

It goes into reconfiguring the mass distribution of the earth-ball system.  Some configurations have more energy, some have less.  The configuration with the ball at altitude has more energy than the ball at the surface.  We can convert energy between these forms by moving the ball to different locations in the earth's gravitational field.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight amount of its kinetic energy converted to heat from the air resistance. However most of its kinetic energy as it rises is being converted to gravitational potential energy. At the topmost point of its trajectory, when it stops rising, it has its greatest potential energy. Then it begins falling back down, converting the potential energy back into kinetic energy. When you throw the ball upwards you are applying an equal and opposite push to the Earth, per Newton's third law of motion. As the ball is attracted back to the Earth, Earth is equally attracted towards the ball, but Earth is so much larger that the forces on it are negligible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there heat associated with the kinetic energy lost by the ball?

Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference.

As the ball goes up and encounters air resistance, it loses some of its kinetic energy due to collisions between air molecules and the ball. That loss of energy increases the internal energy and temperature of the air in the immediate vicinity of the ball as well as the internal energy and temperature of the surface of the ball that contacts the air.

Then the difference in the temperature of the surface of the ball and local air in contact with the ball and the cooler air farther away and cooler interior of the ball creates the condition for heat transfer to the surrounding cooler air and to the cooler interior of the ball. The end result is the ball reaches a maximum height that is less than that if there were no air resistance and all of its initial KE was converted to GPE. Part of the energy loss increases the internal energy and temperature of the surrounding air, and part of the loss increases the internal energy and temperature of the ball.

On the way down instead of all the gravitational potential energy being converted to kinetic energy, some of the potential energy of the ball is converted to an increase in the internal energy and temperature of the surrounding air and the internal energy and temperature of the ball. The end result is the final velocity and kinetic energy of the ball just prior to impacting the ground will be less than that with no air resistance.

> If not, how is energy conserved?

Whether or not air resistance is present, energy is conserved overall. For no air resistance, KE is totally converted to GPE on the way up an GPE is converted totally to KE on the way down, and total *mechanical energy* is conserved. With air resistance part of the KE on the way up and part of the GPE on the way down is converted to internal (microscopic) kinetic energy of the air and ball. Mechanical (macroscopic) KE and GPE is not conserved but total energy is.

> If not, how is momentum conserved?

Momentum is conserved if the net external force acting on a system is zero. So it depends on what constitutes the system.

If one considers the ball, air, and the earth as the system, (and if influence of the gravitational forces of other planets, stars and the moon can be considered negligible), then momentum is conserved.

If one considers the ball alone as the system, then momentum is not conserved because the net force of gravity and air resistance acts on the ball causing a change in its momentum.

Hope this helps.